# Why aren't python and non-python files installed successfully by pip?

Tags: python, pip

My project has file structures like the following:

```
MyParserPkg/
  setup.py
  requirements.txt
  readme.txt
  MANIFEST.in
  doc/
  logs/

  ParserPKG/
  // many python files here
  parser.py
  config.a.ini
  config.b.ini
```

The content of MANIFEST is:

```
include README.txt requirements.txt
include ParserPkg/config.a.ini
include ParserPkg/config.b.ini
```

My setup.py:

```
setup(name='ParserPkg', 
      version='0.1',
      description='A parser for testing',
      packages=['ParserPkg'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Then I do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -e .
```

After the installation, I then check the site-packages of my virtual environment in which the project was installed, and found that it only contains one file:

```
my-envs/dialog-as-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ParserPkg.egg-link
```

And the content of this file, which is the path of my project:

```
/Users/lvisa/MyParserPkg
```

Why does it only contain an egg-link file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `-e` flag, which makes the package editable. As per [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs),

> “Editable” installs are fundamentally [“setuptools develop mode”](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode) installs.

Following that link provides:

> To do this, use the setup.py develop command. It works very similarly to setup.py install or the EasyInstall tool, except that it doesn’t actually install anything. Instead, it creates a special .egg-link file in the deployment directory, that links to your project’s source code. And, if your deployment directory is Python’s site-packages directory, it will also update the easy-install.pth file to include your project’s source code, thereby making it available on sys.path for all programs using that Python installation.

So it "installs" it in the sense that it's available for any other module to use, but it doesn't actually copy over the files, so that you can edit the code and test it out right away.

Comment: However, when I added ParserPkg as a dependency of another project B, and then in package B do 'pip install -r requriements.txt' & 'pip install -e .', it did copied all files under site-packafges. Why is that?

Comment: Technically because you didn't pass the `-e` flag when installing from the `requirements.txt` file, but really because (according to the [usage](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#usage)) you can't use `-r` and `-e` at the same time. So pip just installed everything in `requirements.txt` normally (including ParserPkg), and then it installed project B in editable mode.

Comment: that makes sense. Can you also take a look at this question? which is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502792/how-to-package-a-pure-data-file-project-by-setup-py

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't actually know anything about setting up packages. I just read the docs :)

Comment: hi, Michale, why I can't the the pure-data-file packaging working, even if i read the docs? Can you please copy the files in that question and make a little project to do a quick test and help figure out why it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install -e .` installs packages in "editable" mode. It creates the link and allows you to edit your sources without constantly reinstalling.

So your package is installed correctly. It's how "editable" mode works.

Try `python -c 'import MyParserPkg'`