# How to package a pure data file project by setup.py?

Tags: python

One of my projects only contain data file (.txt) files, and the structure:

```
fsa/
  e/
  f/
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
```

where 'fsa' is the root directory, and e, f are subdirectories, which contains all txt files.

My setup.py:

```
setup(name='fsa',  #to uninstall, use this package name
      version='1.0',
      description='a test file',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

My MANIFEST.in:

```
recursive-include . *
```

I want to recursively include all files under the root directory, so that I use the 'recursive-include' command.

However, either my setup.py or MANIFEST has some problems. It doesn't install the package properly.

Comment: What's the specific issue that happens when you try to install?

Comment: When I install by 'pip install -e .' in this project, it creates an egg-link file in the site-packages directory, which seems fine. However, when I have another project B references this project, and i do "pip install -r requirement.txt" & 'pip install -e .', then I checked the site-packages directory, for this 'fsa' library, it only creates 'fsa-1.0.dist-info' directory, without installing all those data files/directories. I needs them to be installed into the site-packages.

Comment: In project B, one line in the requirements.txt is '../fsa'.